# Different forms of the Adiabatic Theorem

Tags: quantum-computer, adiabatic

I've been reading several papers on Adiabatic Quantum Computation, and I am confused by the form in which the adiabatic approximation condition is presented. For example ([quant-ph/0001106](http://arxiv.org/abs/quant-ph/0001106) eq 2.8) \begin{align*}
\frac{\mbox{max}_{0 \leq s \leq 1} |\langle 1;s| \frac{d\tilde{H}}{ds}|0,s\rangle|}{\left(\mbox{min}_{0 \leq s \leq 1} (E_1(s) - E_0(s))\right)^2} <<T
\end{align*}
where $T$ is the time-scale of the evolution, $s = t/T$, and $H(t) = \tilde{H}(t/T)$.

If you read [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adiabatic_theorem#Proof_of_the_Adiabatic_theorem) or Sakurai (2nd edition Pg 347), we find that we must have:
\begin{align*}
\bigg|\frac{\langle m;t | \frac{dH}{dt}|n;t\rangle}{E_n - E_m}\bigg| <<1
\end{align*}
and using $\langle\frac{dH}{dt}\rangle_{m,n} = \langle\frac{d\tilde{H}}{ds}\rangle_{m,n}\frac{ds}{dt} = \frac{1}{T}\langle\frac{d\tilde{H}}{ds}\rangle_{m,n}$, 
\begin{align*}
\frac{|\langle m;s | \frac{d\tilde{H}}{ds}|n;s\rangle|}{E_n - E_m} <<T
\end{align*}
and thus, if we wish the entire process to be adiabatic, then:
\begin{align*}
\frac{\mbox{max}_{0 \leq s \leq 1}|\langle m;s | \frac{d\tilde{H}}{ds}|n;s\rangle|}{\mbox{min}_{0 \leq s \leq 1}(E_n - E_m)} <<T
\end{align*}
So my main conern: Why in this paper (and others) do we have the quadratic $(E_n-E_m)^2$ in the denominator? This can't be a typo because it turns out to be very important in determining run-times.